# OSMdroid move up the marker on drag

Tags: android, osmdroid

When my marker is draggable I would like to move it up just before drag it because it is under my finger and I don't see it. (It's a trick to see exactly where is the "peak" of my marker)

What I tried to do :

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Marker marker) {
  LogWrapper.debug(MapFragment.class, "onMarkerDragStart()");
  marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(marker.getPosition().getLatitude()+200,marker.getPosition().getLongitude()));
  poiMarkers.invalidate();
  mapView.invalidate();
}
```

But it doesn't work

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(marker.getPosition().getLatitude()+200,marker.getPosition().getLongitude()));
```

+200 degrees? This is largely too much!

> it is under my finger and I don't see it - It's a trick to see exactly where is the "peak" of my marker.

=> I agree. I imagine that a good solution would be to have an appropriate marker icon design (higher than usual for instance?).

Comment: 200 degres, it may be too much, but my point doesn't move at all...
 Okay, I didn't think to the solution : I'll create a marker with a blank at the bottom.

Comment: My first feedback about the +200 degrees was irrelevant - sorry for that => In fact, the Marker dragging mechanism is forcing the Marker position to the event position (the position of your finger). So, you cannot move your marker this way. Usually, when dragging start, you should typically see the marker "bumping", as its hotspot immediately moves to the finger position.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the code into `onMarkerDrag()`.

```
@Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
            marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(marker.getPosition().getLatitude()+0.00015,marker.getPosition().getLongitude()));
            map.invalidate();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially a lot too late for your app, but upon running into the same problem, I modified the marker to provide exactly this functionality.

See [this PR on github](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/pull/561)... modify `moveToEventPosition` to include an offset:

```
public void moveToEventPosition(final MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView){
    float offsetY = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, mDragOffsetY, mapView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    final Projection pj = mapView.getProjection();
    mPosition = (GeoPoint) pj.fromPixels((int)event.getX(), (int)(event.getY()-offsetY));
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

EDIT: pr has been merged...